# Seg fault when using strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I am trying to read each number from an input that looks like this:

```
179    2358 5197    867 
5541    172 4294    1397
2637    136 3222    591
```

... and get the min/max of each row going line by line and then getting each number in the line using strtok, but I get a seg fault error in the second while loop.

The code:

```
#include "header.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int8_t* line = malloc(sizeof(int8_t) * 75);
  int8_t* temp;

  int32_t minim, maxim;
  int32_t current;

  stdin = fopen("stdin", "r");
  while (fgets(line, 75 * sizeof(int8_t), stdin)) {
    printf("%s", line);
    temp = strtok(line," \n\t");
    maxim = minim = atoi(temp);

    while (temp != NULL) {
      current = atoi(temp);
      temp = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");

      if (current < minim)
        minim = current;
      if (current > maxim)
        maxim = current;

    } 

    printf("\nMin and max: %d %d\n", minim, maxim);
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
# define HEADER_H

# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

  typedef                   char  int8_t;
  typedef   signed     short int int16_t;
  typedef   signed           int int32_t;
  typedef   signed long long int int64_t;

  typedef unsigned          char  uint8_t;
  typedef unsigned     short int uint16_t;
  typedef unsigned           int uint32_t;
  typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t;

#endif
```

I just don't get what it might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to open `stdin`, it is already open. Is there any reason not to use `scanf` here? Given the simple and regular input.

Comment: `stdin = fopen("stdin", "r");` -- that's opening a file named "stdin" for reading. You also never check if opening that file succeeded before reading from the `stdin` handle. **Undefined behaviour**, you die.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The suggestion to read a line at a time using `fgets()` and parsing it in-memory (as opposed to `*scanf()`) is frequently made. No reason for criticism there (if only he had done it right).

Comment: You go `atoi` on `temp` before checking if it's `NULL`. **Undefined behaviour**, you die.

Comment: I am opening stdin because I am changing my standard input to read from a file. I cannot also use scanf in the standard way because I need to work with numbers from each line.

Comment: You don't want to "read your standard input from a file" that way. You either read from a file (via `fopen()`, or you read from standard input, i.e. `stdin` (which might or might not be fed to your executable from a file, or a pipe, it doesn't really matter). What matters is that you don't check your return values...

Comment: `uint8_t` et al. are identifiers reserved by the standard library (`<stdint.h>`), and compiling your header.h with a conforming compiler fails because of that.

Comment: @DevSolar The header is not included, so no reason to fail from that reason...

Comment: `line` and `temp` are declared `int8_t *`, but should really be `char *`.

Comment: You don't `fclose()` the file you opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so...

1. Your `<header.h>` breaks on my compiler, as it redefines the identifiers `int8_t` et al. reserved by the standard. (Not quite correct of the compiler to complain, as the relevant headers were not included, but there you are.) If you define your own types, use your own identifiers. Or include `<stdint.h>` for the "real" intX_t types (yes I know a certain "big" compiler doesn't have that header).
2. The simplest thing, of course, is to use `char *` for strings instead of `int8_t *`. (The signed-ness of `char` is implementation-defined, and anyway a good compiler complains rather loudly about the many implicit casts *not* using `char *` involves.)
3. You use the exact-width type `int32_t` for your `minim` and `maxim`, but neglect to use the proper `printf()` width specifiers to go with that (`PRId32`, specified in `<inttypes.h>`). As I cannot see any specific need for exact-width types, I replaced them with plain `int` (for which a mere `%d` suffices).
4. Once you've done that, remove mention of `sizeof( char )`, as that is *by definition* `1`.
5. **Do check** return values of functions. `fopen()` can fail. Make sure it didn't.
6. Don't "reuse" the `stdin` file descriptor. It's just confusing all around. Whether your `stdin` comes from the terminal or a file or a pipe is decided by how you call your executable. If you open a file, use a `FILE * handle_name`, not `stdin`. And besides, `stdin` *is* an open file descriptor (namely your program's standard input), so you would have to use `freopen()`, not `fopen()`, to have it properly receiving from a different source. The simplest thing is to actually use `stdin` as-is (which also gives you the greatest flexibility in *using* your program).
7. **Do** release resources you acquired. `free()` memory. `fclose()` files. Many operating systems protect you from this kind of negligence and clean up after you. Some don't.

And once you've fixed those problems you sneezed at in comments...

```
#include <stdlib.h>                           // <-- added
#include <stdio.h>                            // <-- added
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* line = malloc(75);                    // <-- turned to char *
  char* temp;                                 // <-- turned to char *

  int minim, maxim;                           // <-- turned to int
  int current;                                // <-- turned to int

  while (fgets(line, 75, stdin)) {            // <-- using stdin directly
    printf("%s", line);
    temp = strtok(line," \n\t");
    maxim = minim = atoi(temp);

    while (temp != NULL) {
      current = atoi(temp);
      temp = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");

      if (current < minim)
        minim = current;
      if (current > maxim)
        maxim = current;

    }

    printf("\nMin and max: %d %d\n", minim, maxim);
  }

  printf("\n");
  free( line );                                // <-- releasing memory
  return 0;
}
```

...your program works:

```
./testme.exe < file.dat                      # feeding file.dat to stdin
179    2358 5197    867

Min and max: 179 5197
5541    172 4294    1397

Min and max: 172 5541
2637    136 3222    591

Min and max: 136 3222
```

Lesson here: Code cleanly. Enable strictest compiler warnings, and *heed* them.

As for overwriting `stdin` with the results of `fopen()` as you did, the standard states (emphasis mine):

> 229) [...] [`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`] **need not be modifiable lvalues** to which the value returned by the `fopen` function may be assigned.

Comment: To the editor: Yes, I mistyped `sizeof( char * )`. No, a char is *not* defined to have 8 bits, it's defined to have `CHAR_BIT` bits. I retained OP's source formatting on purpose to make the changes stand out more to him (and source formatting is a matter of taste anyhow).

Answer (score 0):

```
stdin = fopen("stdin", "r");
```

This isn’t doing what you think it is.  This tries to open a file in the current directory named “stdin”.  It does **not** open the standard input stream.

You most likely don’t have a file by this name, so this function probably fails and returns NULL.  And because you don’t check the return value, you pass a NULL pointer to `fgets`.  This invokes undefined behavior, which in this case manifests as a crash.

The standard input stream is already open when your program starts.  So remove the `fopen` call and it should work.

Comment: @Marcus: **You don't check.**

Comment: @DevSolar That's not the error. It reads the first line properly then it breaks, and I forgot to write this in the post...

Comment: Note too that you can't necessarily reassign `stdin` like that.  You probably can on modern Linux.  On classic Unix, it probably wouldn't work.  That's why the [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) function is part of standard C (even though I linked to the POSIX specification).